# How can I prove that $c^n$ is upper bound of $n^k$?

Tags: solution-verification

The proof can be using calculus or finding a $n_o$ from which it holds that $c^n>n^k$ for $k \ge 1$ and $c>1$

Comment: If you want to prove that $c^n>n^k$ for all $k\geq1$, $c>1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then there's a problem since that's not true, however if you want to prove that for all $k\geq1$, $c>1$ we have that eventually $c^n>n^k$ then you can do so by computing $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{c^x}{x^k}$ and for that you can use L'Hopital's rule $k$ times.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as @IgnacioHenríquez. Another approach is: $c^n>n^k \iff n\ln(c) > k\ln(n) \iff n/\ln(n) > k/\ln(c)$ where the last term is constant.

Comment: Thank you both!